# Pie chart as scatter plot with non-numeric axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, facet-wrap

I want to plot weighted pie-charts, with a non-numeric axis per `Season`. Every basket is a pie-chart, weighted by `Frequency` and showing the distribution of fruit in each basket, in order of `Rank` (y axis). [Example of what I want the plot to look like is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NszuC.png), but instead of color by frequency, to have the pie-charts instead.

`scatterpie` did not work as my x axis is non-numeric.

I have the dataframe below:

```
fruit <- data.frame(
  Basket = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"),
  Apples = c(50, 30, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 5, 15, 40, 220, 150, 0, 0, 0),
  Oranges = c(1, 10, 25, 20, 15, 15, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Plums = c(0, 9, 5, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Grapes = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 50, 30, 20, 4, 5, 10, 25, 5, 4),
  Frequency = c(51, 49, 40, 39, 25, 95, 75, 50, 45, 44, 225, 160, 25, 5, 4),
  Rank = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  Season = c("Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter")
)
```

which looks like:

```
> fruit
   Basket Apples Oranges Plums Grapes Frequency Rank Season
1       A     50       1     0      0        51    1 Summer
2       B     30      10     9      0        49    2 Summer
3       C     10      25     5      0        40    3 Summer
4       D      5      20     5      0        39    4 Summer
5       E      5      15     5      0        25    5 Summer
6       F     10      15    10     60        95    1 Autumn
7       G     10      10     5     50        75    2 Autumn
8       H      5      10     5     30        50    3 Autumn
9       I     15       0    10     20        45    4 Autumn
10      J     40       0     0      4        44    5 Autumn
11      K    220       0     0      5       225    1 Winter
12      L    150       0     0     10       160    2 Winter
13      M      0       0     0     25        25    3 Winter
14      N      0       0     0      5         5    4 Winter
15      O      0       0     0      4         4    5 Winter
```

What I did so far is this:

```
fruit_melt<-melt(fruit, id.vars=c("Basket","Frequency","Rank","Season"), 
                 measure.vars=colnames(fruit)[!names(fruit) %in% c("Basket","Frequency","Rank","Season")])

ggplot(fruit_melt, aes(x=Frequency/2, y=value, colour=variable, fill=variable, width=Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, position="fill", stat = "identity") +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Season+Rank+(-Frequency), ncol= 5) +theme_void()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, margin=margin(b=20, unit="pt"), face="bold"))+
  scale_fill_carto_d(direction = -1) +
  scale_color_carto_d(direction = -1)
```

[Picture with current pie chart look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J6dx.png)

But I would really like to have instead:

1. an x axis displaying the rank (top to bottom)
2. a y axis displaying the seasons, and the basket pie charts stacked in order of rank
3. the min size of a pie chart to be bigger. I cannot see the smallest ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you could achieve your desired result via `scatterpie`. But it requires some data warngling steps. Adapting my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72782239/12993861) to your case you could convert your `Season` variable to a numeric. Additionally, you have to `rescale`  the result to the range of the `Rank` variable as we have to use `coord_fixed` for `scatterpie`. Also we have to compute the radius  manually. Note, for a nice look you have to scale the radius which reuqires sime fiddling, e.g. I used a scaling factor of .025.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(scatterpie)
library(ggplot2)

fruit_long <- fruit |>
  pivot_longer(-c(Rank, Season, Basket, Frequency), names_to = "fruit") |>
  mutate(y = as.numeric(factor(Season, levels = c("Summer", "Autumn", "Winter"))), 
         y = scales::rescale(y, to = range(Rank)), value = value) |>
  group_by(Basket) |>
  mutate(r = 2 * sqrt(sum(value) / 2 / pi)) |> 
  ungroup()

ggplot() +
  geom_scatterpie(aes(x = Rank, y = y, fill = fruit, r = .025 * r), 
                  data = fruit_long, cols = "fruit", long_format = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = unique(fruit_long$y), 
    labels = unique(fruit_long$Season)) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
fruit <- data.frame(
  Basket = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"),
  Apples = c(50, 30, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 5, 15, 40, 220, 150, 0, 0, 0),
  Oranges = c(1, 10, 25, 20, 15, 15, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Plums = c(0, 9, 5, 5, 5, 10, 5, 5, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Grapes = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 50, 30, 20, 4, 5, 10, 25, 5, 4),
  Frequency = c(51, 49, 40, 39, 25, 95, 75, 50, 45, 44, 225, 160, 25, 5, 4),
  Rank = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  Season = c("Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter")
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to tweak it in a way to show exactly how I want them. I did not find the almost similar post from before.